# Is it possible to tell the android application to download a db from somewhere to the phone?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am curious to know if I can tell the android application to download a specific db file from somewhere and access it like CRUD based stuff to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you need to download the file than you can load it into your db, [use this gist](https://gist.github.com/donaldlittlepie/1271795) to load it into the db.

 the Webb has a lot of examples how to download a file with your app, simply save it on your sd card and load it from where you saved it to instead of the assets like in the gist

Comment: Do you know any references I can refer to that shows you how to download a file from a URL and access that same file on the tablet or phone?

Comment: Sure - Check out http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1521 (pay attenetion to save and open the file from the same dir better place a constant for that path, ps @imGreg you could have google that..)